# Function that filter arrays and create new array after

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, filter, return

I have to creater function ( lets call it filterItems), that will filter 2 arrays ( take all the numbers above 0) and the result should return new array with all the number above 0 from 2 arrays.

f.e input

```
[1, -2, 3] [1, 0]
```

output

```
[1, 3, 1]
```

I tried by using map, but it failed.

```
function filterItems(arr,array) {
return arr.map(number => arr > 0 , array > 0)
}
```

Thank eveyrone for their time and i will be grateful for any tips.

Comment: You can simply merge the two arrays and then filter all items > 0: `const result = [...array1, ...array2].filter(item => item > 0)`?

Comment: for exercise i have to create function called "filterItems". so i dont know if it will count ( in totally new, i know css and html, but im learning jss to uderstand what exacly going with apps).

Comment: It does not change anything: `function filterItems(arr, array) { return [...arr, ...array].filter(item => item > 0) }`. It is exactly the same concept, but you use the resulting array as a the returned value for a function instead of assigning it to a variable.

Comment: Tahnk you!!! I wish i be that smart.

Comment: It has nothing to do with being smart; it is a matter of experience and familiarity with the language... [mode:grumpy-grandpa] something that you can acquire quicker, if you try a little bit harder to solve the exercises by yourself rather than giving up too quickly and looking for someone else's support.[/mode:grumpy-grandpa] ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate the arrays and then filter out the numbers `<= 0`.

This approach is a little more extended because receives the handler for the function `Array.prototype.filter`.

```js
const filterItems = (arr, array, fn = (n) => n > 0) => arr.concat(array).filter(fn);

console.log(filterItems([1, -2, 3], [1, 0]));
console.log(filterItems([1, -2, 3], [1, 0], (n) => n <= 0));
```